# Procedure in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, procedure

this is my php code. Procedure works.

This should be thingy that calls procedure to work:

- code on the bottom of this wall of text -

It does nothing. Blank.

procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dodaj_osobe
         (do_pesel     decimal(11),
 do_imie   VARCHAR(45),
 do_nazwisko    VARCHAR(45),
 do_telefon     decimal(9),
 do_adres     VARCHAR(45),
 do_nr_konta     decimal(20),
 do_zarobek    decimal(8,2))
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
INSERT INTO baza_osob
(pesel,imie,nazwisko,telefon,adres,nr_konta,zarobek)
VALUES
(do_pesel,do_imie,do_nazwisko,do_telefon,do_adres,do_nr_konta,do_zarobek);
```

Can someone find me an error here? It's probably something small.. but I just cannot see 
it.

@EDIT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<,

It looks like this now, still nothing changed.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);

$nazwabazydanych = "projekt";
if (!$pesel || !$imie || !$nazwisko || !$telefon || !$adres || !$nr_konta || !$zarobek)

 {
        print "Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola";
        exit;
 }

$pesel = mysql_real_escape_string($pesel);
$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($imie);  
$nazwisko = mysql_real_escape_string($nazwisko);
$telefon = mysql_real_escape_string($telefon);
$adres = mysql_real_escape_string($adres);
$nr_konta = mysql_real_escape_string($nr_konta);
$zarobek = mysql_real_escape_string($zarobek);


$db = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db)  
        {  
        print "Nie można nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych";
        exit;
        }

mysql_select_db("$nazwabazydanych");

$query = mysql_query("CALL dodaj_osobe ('$pesel','$imie','$nazwisko','$telefon','$adres','$nr_konta','$zarobek')"); 

?>
```

AND ERROR:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: pesel in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\lool.php on line 5
Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola
```

Comment: NO ERROR. Just blank page.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? And PHP configured so that it displays the errors?

Comment: try `mysql_select_db("$nazwabazydanych");`, note dollar sign before variable name.

Comment: Remove the `@` from `$db = mysql_pconnect("localho5st", "root", "");` and never use it again. And go for PDO instead of mysql extension.

Comment: removed @. but still.. wow this is harsh.

Comment: addslashes is to sql injection prevention as wet toilet paper is to drying out New Jersey after hurricane Sandy. **DO NOT USE IT**.

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string instead of addslashes.

Comment: What can I use it instead of it? Or maybe just cut off those lines of text?

Comment: Changed it. Still getting the same error about pesel in line 5.

Comment: There you go. The reason why you don't get anything from SQL connection is that your script hangs on the first condition. `if (!$pesel || !$imie || !$nazwisko || !$telefon || !$adres || !$nr_konta || !$zarobek) {}` contains `exit`, which stops the script. From that I think you're getting those variables from some form. If so, it's a wrong approach. You should use $_POST['input_name'].

Comment: Yeah, I can read that. But why?

Comment: Because those variables are not defined anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to write localhost instead of localho5st

Comment: I am doing this on purpose, so it can send me an error. It does not send anything.

Comment: If I paste in before <? it will just show "error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);" If inside script - noting

Comment: there is still an @ in front of @$db

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. It showed an error, undefined variable pesel. I wrote it in the question desription.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @$db = mysql_pconnect("localho5st", "root", "");
```

Is is **localhost** or **localho5st**

Just wondering...

Comment: I did it on purpose to check if the scropt will run me at least an error. Nope, nothing.